# Drupal installation failed

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I'm facing a problem with Drupal installation. Basically this is the first time ever that I try to install Drupal on my pc (Windows 10). I have followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLtaXuX0nEZk9MKY_ClWcPkGtOEGyLTyCO&v=4kvYfxOR3GY) on Youtube and I did everything that he said and after I installed the *Acquia Dev Desktop 2* and when I tried loading the local site link which is **http://www.drupal-8.dd:8083/install.php** in my browser I get this error message:

> The www.drupal-8.dd page isn’t working
>
> www.drupal-8.dd didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

So what's going wrong ?! What should I do

**Note:** I'm installing Drupal 8 and the Apache and MySQL is also turned on in Acquia

Comment: Even it is possible your site will most likely work on linux machine so it's better to develop in it's natural environment. Better go for some linux based virtual machine. Even better use Vagrant to minimize server setup work.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 8 requires PHP's extension called `OPcache` to be enabled, maybe that is the problem. After [enabling](http://adrian.sutantio.me/2015/10/enable-php-opcache-extension-on-windows.html) it, restart your apache and try accessing the site.